# is ‘StackOverFlow’ an acceptable username on SO?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I just saw a post by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297907/stackoverflow) and thought it had been written by an admin of the site. But having had a look at their reputation (464 ATM), I don’t suppose so.

I consider the choice of their username misleading, but there is no way to report a user.

Comment: "Admin's" have ♦'s. That's good enough for me.

Comment: There's well over a hundred users with "stackoverflow" somewhere in the name...

Comment: @Mysticial that’s not trivial for everyone, especially newbies.

Comment: @törzsmókus I don't see how it's any worse than any other site or forum. Some sites have different colored names for mods/admins, here they get fairly eye-catching ♦'s behind their names and "Moderator ♦" written on their profile. All of which is non-intuitive to a new user.

Comment: whats problem in that name .. you can select name you want .. except some bad words

Comment: I am baffled to see getting downvotes instead of answers like ‘yes it is (because...)’ or ‘no it is not (because...)’ :(

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Bart thanks, I wasn’t aware of that. but if I ask a question which causes disagreement, I may lose all my rep...?

Comment: @törzsmókus Potentially. If it's really terribly disagreed with. Then again, it's Meta rep. It doesn't mean a thing. This is the only Meta within the network that is its own site and has reputation. So don't worry too much.

Comment: @törzsmókus - But you didn't necessarily just ask a question. It's a good question, but it's the answer you posted in your question, your biased opinion, that people most likely are voting on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is misleading since it may give the impression the the person answering is someone employed by Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange. I have no idea why such a username would be allowed. It is misleading and unnecessary.

It *may* also be a breach of the terms of service, specifically:

> Subscriber may not (a) select or use as a profile name a name of another person with the intent to impersonate that person; or (b) use as a profile name a name subject to any rights of a person other than Subscriber without appropriate authorization.

IANAL but I think impersonation is a real problem here (a "person" can also be a company,at least in the Swedish legal system where I live), and it is also a trademarked name (though usage as a nickname may not in itself constitute a trademark misuse).

Comment: Suppose it was edited to be "Stack Overflow User"?

Comment: Having a look at the 31 users who have named themselves like that (only 8 of which used the correct spelling by the way), I'm hard pressed to believe that there will ever be serious confusion here. Heck, recently a user was brought up on Meta who named himself a moderator of SO on his personal blog. If anyone would make claims to have more authority than they do, we have a community that would pick up on that pretty rapidly. Theoretically you have somewhat of a point. In practice though I don't see much of an issue.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is just fine. Not particularly imaginative, and I wouldn't use it, but users are entirely free to select any username they want. Unless they go for something particularly offensive, in which rare case that might be changed.

Should you ever happen upon something like that, flag one of their posts for moderator attention using the "other" option, and explain you have a problem with the username. However, in this particular case there is no need.

Moderators of the site however, will stand out by the ♦ character next to their username. And should that still not be clear enough, then you can find a list of moderators on every site. Go to the Users page and select the moderators tab. For Meta Stack Overflow it's this page for example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators